# Find the Elements within the given distance within Tree

Tags: recursion, tree, distance

I have a tree which as certain elements, I have a method essentially returns a list of elements that are within the distance.

Example

[image]

In the tree above, once I have my method, I should be able to input a data and distance. Lets say the data I input is 1 and the distance is 2. In this case, the method should output elements, [2,3,4] because I should be able to output data that is less than or equal to the given distance.

I know how to output data that have a distance of 2 away, but I am struggling to include data that includes data that is 1 away as well.

```
    void printkdistanceNodeDown(Node node, int k)  
    { 
        if (node == null || k < 0) 
            return; 
        if (k == 0)  
        { 
            System.out.print(node.data); 
            System.out.println(""); 
            return; 
        } 

        // Recur for left and right subtrees 
        printkdistanceNodeDown(node.left, k - 1); 
        printkdistanceNodeDown(node.right, k - 1); 
    } 

    int printkdistanceNode(Node node, Node target, int k)  
    { 
        if (node == null) 
            return -1; 

        if (node == target)  
        { 
            printkdistanceNodeDown(node, k); 
            return 0; 
        } 

        // Recur for left subtree 
        int dl = printkdistanceNode(node.left, target, k); 

        // Check if target node was found in left subtree 
        if (dl != -1)  
        { 

            if (dl + 1 == k)  
            { 
                System.out.print(node.data); 
                System.out.println(""); 
            } 

            else
                printkdistanceNodeDown(node.right, k - dl - 2); 

            // Add 1 to the distance and return value for parent calls 
            return 1 + dl; 
        } 

        // MIRROR OF ABOVE CODE FOR RIGHT SUBTREE 
        // Note that we reach here only when node was not found in left  
        // subtree 
        int dr = printkdistanceNode(node.right, target, k); 
        if (dr != -1)  
        { 
            if (dr + 1 == k)  
            { 
                System.out.print(node.data); 
                System.out.println(""); 
            }  
            else 
                printkdistanceNodeDown(node.left, k - dr - 2); 
            return 1 + dr; 
        } 

        // If target was neither present in left nor in right subtree 
        return -1; 
    }
```

Comment: explain what is the `target` in your second function, and why you have two recursive functions

Comment: Does your question only applies to the first function? If so, the answer is easy.

Comment: The target function is essentially the node you must find and be able to find the nodes that are certain distances from that node.Prints all nodes at distance k from a given target node.This function returns distance of root from target node

Comment: but why do you need two `node` and `target` ? What's the purpose of `node` then? If your input is only a node  and a distance, why you have 3 parameters?...

Comment: Maybe my thought process is wrong. I am essentially finding all elements within a certain distance from the given data. I was essentially planning on having 2 helper methods where the first one that adds the nodes on the path (root to target node) and essentially find distance between nodes on the path and target node. My second one would essentially add the children if they are within the distance. Is there a simpler way to do this? If so, how would it be done?

Comment: ok, i'm not getting it but it's fine. Your code outputs what for `1` input?